# Mensa Sample IQ test question - squares, rectangles and triangles in big squares

Tags: pattern, visual

I took a sample Mensa IQ test at the [Mensa France Website](https://www.mensa-idf.org/?action=tests_exemples) and encountered a question which I wasn't able to solve:

[image]

The instructions were written in French:

> Parmi les 5 figures proposées, quelles sont les 2 qui ne vont pas avec les 3 autres ?

Which translates to:

> Among the five figures proposed, which two figures do not match the other three?

I could not figure out which two figures are different. To me, on one perspective, they are all the same, on another, they are all different. I then figured out that the correct answers were options B and E, by trying out all possible combinations and seeing which combination gives a higher score. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Source: [Mensa France](https://www.mensa-idf.org/?action=tests_exemples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Figures B and E are such that the small square/rectangle and small triangle inscribed in the big square don't share a line segment (in full or in part).
>
>  To elaborate,  Figure A has a side of the small square that forms part of the base of the triangle. Figure C has both the small square and small triangle sharing a base. Figure D has the small rectangle and small triangle sharing a common line segment which forms aside for the rectangle and the base for the triangle. Thus, in this way and probably only in this way, B and E are the odd ones out.

Comment: Great job on this answer! This is a very good first explanation, and also the best answer since you've elaborated very well.

Answer (score 2):

> To be honest I see two possibilities 1) B and E because the sides of the two shapes (square and triangle) don't touch and 2) B and C because one shape is inside another.

Comment: It could also be "A and E, because all three sides of the triangle have different lengths"; or "C and D, because the triangle and rectangle share two vertices"...

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker, I do agree with you, this question has a lot of solutions with valid explanations, and there even isn't an explanation given on the site to explain why the answer is B and E.